# Using jQuery .error() to load replacement image for when an img tag doesn't load properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I'm just wondering why the following doesn't seem to work for me (tried with Chrome and FF):

```
<img src="" />
<img src="asdf" />

// Change broken images to a placeholder image
$('img').error(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/100');
});
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43Yrm/)

Comment: I guess, It gets triggered when you set the src, not for the image that has erraneous src in the html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onerror` event has already fired, so you need to create a new image and listen for an error event on that :

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var img  = new Image(),
        self = this;

    img.onerror = function(){
        $(self).prop('src', 'http://placehold.it/100');
    }

    img.src = this.src;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/43Yrm/7/)

Comment: This seems to work but I'm still trying to understand it. How does creating a completely new image object relate to the original img tag? Is this new image on top of the original broken image?

Comment: @skube - it's nowhere, it's not appended to the DOM at all, it's just used to check if the image could be loaded or not.

Comment: So the new image object tries to load each actual image src and then if it encounters an `onerror` it will set the the actual image's src to the placeholder?  I guess what was confusing me is the order. I would think the `img.src = this.src` should come before the function expression, at least in my mind.

Comment: It shouldn't, setting the source is what triggers the load to start, so setting the source before the onload or onerror handler are set can cause those event handlers to not fire if the image loads or errors out too fast, so you should always set the source after the event handlers are set.

Answer (score 2):

this should answer your question

The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error event, which is why the example sets the src attribute after attaching the handler. Also, the error event may not be correctly fired when the page is served locally; error relies on HTTP status codes and will generally not be triggered if the URL uses the file: protocol.

http://api.jquery.com/error/

Comment: That is insightful to why this solution works - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images